# Stop borders from expanding into Margins/Padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

I am trying to create my meta section for my blog posts using twitter bootstrap. The issue I'm running into is the borders around my DIVs are expanding out into the negative margins of the row and I can't figure out why (borders in my other divs are not having this problem).

If someone could help me figure out how to stop the top and bottom borders from expanding into the left and right padding/margins, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the applicable CSS:

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;

}

.meta-entry-right{
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: gray;
}

.meta-entry{
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: gray; 
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<footer class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry">
                    Author: <br>
                    <?php the_author_link(); ?> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry">
                    Posted On:<br>
                    <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry">
                    Categorized:<br>
                    <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry-right">
                    Discussion:<br>
                    <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number(); ?></a>
                </div>
            </footer>
```

You can view the issue in action here: http://onedirectionconnection.com/tester/

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I get what you are after but if you do this.

```
.footer .row { margin:0; }
```

I think you can apply your borders as you want.

Answer (score 0):

use the `box-sizing` attribute on your elements.

To apply a natural box layout model to all elements add this to your CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Comment: That's the weird thing. That code has already been applied via bootstrap. http://onedirectionconnection.com/tester/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/resources/bootstrap-3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

Simply by adding `span` tags to each content inside the divs you can generate borders without margin be bothering your code.

```
span{
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3Rvt/)

Comment: The issue is, I want the borders to expand across the length of the meta information, I just don't want the borders to expand into the negative margins of the .row div.